# webpack is not recognizing .jsx file extension

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

In our project, I'm trying to refactor all our components to have a `.jsx`file extension rather than `.js`. My webpack.config.babel file now looks like this:

```
import fs from "fs"

const babelrc = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./.babelrc"))

export default {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: babelrc,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: babelrc,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

However when I try to run `import Main from './components/Main/Main';`
 in my client.js file, it shows me

```
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/foo/src/components/Main/Main.js'
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?/ webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/client.js
```

I'm new to babel and webpack. What other places to I need to register the jsx file extension?

Comment: My code looks like this
```{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: path.join(__dirname, '/../src')
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `resolve.extensions`:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions

You can add the following to your Webpack config to also automatically resolve files with the `.jsx` extension by adding the following to your config:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
}
```

<sub>Btw, you can also optimize your loader config by removing the separate `.jsx` loader and make the first loader `test` for `/\.jsx?$/`</sub>